# Google Sheets Page Size recognition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make an "Estimate maker" for work. This has 1 function I can not figure out. Since google sheets will not allow me to add a custom header with logo, I am trying to have one tab write to another tab just row by row, and once it recognizes the height of all rows written has reached the maximum size of a page (when printed to PDF) it will recognize it and then put the header rows in again, then keep going with the script until it hits the max size for the next page and does it again. I deal with 100's of orders a day and they are all in google sheets, This function will make it possible to automate a lot of this. Every one will have a custom header, and the format of the line items below can change(all easy to do with a spread sheet), the height of the cells below it can change, so I need it to recognize the sizing before it puts in the header again.

This is what I have, It writes the first header, then does not recognize the sizing and just writes line by line so it never gets another header. It will always be the same size paper for the PDF.  Please help. This is the latest attempt, Im getting outside of my abilities now LOL. Also here is a link to the Test sheet, anyone can edit to help. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GBdlMq5C_VqcToRj1wx9KzuOYRgagOzUz95QMJQ-tKg/edit#gid=719770573

```
function generatePDFWithConsistentHeaders() {
  var sourceSheetName = "Maker"; 
  var destinationSheetName = "PDF Maker"; 
  var headerRange = "A1:G2"; // 
  var dataRange = "A1:E200"; // 

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);

  // Clear the destination sheet before copying new data
  destinationSheet.clearContents();

  // Copy and paste the header to the top of each page
  var headerRangeCopy = sourceSheet.getRange(headerRange);
  var pageCount = Math.ceil(sourceSheet.getLastRow() / destinationSheet.getMaxRows());

  for (var page = 0; page < pageCount; page++) {
    var startRow = page * destinationSheet.getMaxRows() + 1;
    var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, headerRangeCopy.getNumRows(), headerRangeCopy.getNumColumns());
    headerRangeCopy.copyTo(destinationRange);
  }

  // Copy the data row by row
  var dataRangeCopy = sourceSheet.getRange(dataRange);
  var destinationRow = headerRangeCopy.getNumRows() + 1;

  for (var i = 1; i <= dataRangeCopy.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var sourceRow = dataRangeCopy.getRow() + i - 1;
    var sourceValues = dataRangeCopy.getSheet().getRange(sourceRow, dataRangeCopy.getColumn(), 1, dataRangeCopy.getNumColumns()).getDisplayValues()[0];
    var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationRow, 1, 1, sourceValues.length);
    destinationRange.setValues([sourceValues]);
    destinationRow++;

    // Insert a new header row at the start of each page
    if (destinationRow % destinationSheet.getMaxRows() === 1 && destinationRow <= destinationSheet.getMaxRows() * pageCount) {
      var headerRangeCopy = sourceSheet.getRange(headerRange);
      var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationRow, 1, headerRangeCopy.getNumRows(), headerRangeCopy.getNumColumns());
      headerRangeCopy.copyTo(destinationRange);
      destinationRow++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `pageCount` logic? When I am trying to replicate it, it returns `1` because the `destinationSheet.getMaxRows()` is 1000 and the `sourceSheet.getLastRow()` is 200, so 200/1000 is `0.2`. Place that result into `Math.ceil()`, then it returns `1`, which doesn't make any sense when used `1` as the value of the `pageCount` in your first **For loop**.

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

> ***NOTE**: This answer is intended to serve as a starting point or reference for your project. It's important to note that the community members do not provide coding services.*

In my understanding of your question, you gather **data** from the **Maker** sheet tab & the **headers** from the **`A1:G2`** range from the same sheet. Then, you identify the *"maximum size of a page" or (`pageCount`)*, chunk each **data** per `pageCount` & add the headers at the beginning of each chunk from the **data**.

In my replication, your current script is quite inefficient as you run the `copyTo()` inside a "for loop" method. This slows down your script. Perhaps you can try eliminating repeated API calls in a loop by processing all of your raw sheet data in one way via `forEach` inside the `do-while` loop & re-add the new sheet data in your destination sheet in one process *(via `setValues()`)* outside of any looping method, as seen on the sample below.

***Sample Tweaked Script***

> In the sample `pageCount` below, since I can't fully understand your logic in your original script in getting the `pageCount`. I based my sample `pageCount` value on your ***'WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE'*** sheet tab, which I suppose is **50** per page. Just in case you think your question has been misinterpreted, feel free to update your question for better understanding.

```
function generatePDFWithConsistentHeaders() {
  var sourceSheetName = "Maker";
  var destinationSheetName = "PDF Maker";
  var headerRange = "A1:G2"; // 
  var dataRange = "A1:G200"; //

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  var headerData = sourceSheet.getRange(headerRange).getValues();
  var rawData = sourceSheet.getRange(dataRange).getValues();
  var pageCount = 50 //NOTE: I do not know your exact that logic here, but let's base on your sample expected result, which I suppose is '50' per page.

  do {
    rawData.forEach((_, index) => (index + 1) == pageCount && (rawData.splice(index + 1, 0, ...headerData)));
    console.log(`pageCount: ${pageCount}\nCurrent rawData length: ${rawData.length}`);//Console log for review
    pageCount = pageCount + 50;
  } while (pageCount <= rawData.length);

  //Set the result in the 'destinationSheet'
  destinationSheet.getRange(1, 1, rawData.length, rawData[0].length).setValues(rawData)
}
```

***Demo***

- *Console log:*

[image]

- ***PDF Maker** sheet tab:*
  [image]

I hope this answer will be helpful to you in your actual project. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to respond.

***References***

- [JavaScript Array forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Javascript Short Circuiting Operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-short-circuiting/)